# Media starts, stops and skips randomly, maybe the keyboard is too hot?

Tags: audio, apple-music, mediaplayer, intel

Any media I have playing or active is randomly pausing, starting or (if music/playlist) skipping to the next track/video. This is not an issue to do with a single media client as I get it with everything (Spotify, YouTube, iPlayer etc). If no media is active or playing, then my Macbook opens Apple Music and plays whatever random audio files I have!

I followed the steps here - https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251230091 which includes resetting SMC and NVRAM. But this is no good.

My keyboard does get hot occasionally, which I suspect might be interfering with the function keys and causing a problem there. **Edit: maybe not, as after checking keyboard viewer, changing the function keys and using an external keyboard as per @Allen's suggestions (see comments), this problem persists!**

I'm running macOS 11.5.1 (20G80) (macOS Big Sur) on a Intel Core i5 MacBook Air (13-inch, 2017). I probably ought to update but have very little space on here and seems to be fine mostly (apart from this!)

Any suggestions? <strike>Or how do I disable the function keys completely?</strike>

#### Update 26/4/2023

It appears to be an issue with the headphone jack as this triggers (although it still does it randomly) when I move or wiggle my headphone cable. Connecting headphones to bluetooth do not cause this problem at all.

Comment: If you suspect the keyboard, get a cheap USB keyboard and try that for a little while to see if the problem goes away

Comment: Yeah I'll try that, thanks. How do I disable the built-in keyboard? @Allan

Comment: You shouldn’t have to disable it.  You can also try the [keyboard viewer](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/mac) to see if those keys are being pressed.  Alternatively, you could change them to standard Fn keys in settinfs

Comment: @Allan Hm, okay so the keyboard viewer isn't showing anything being pressed and changing to normal fn keys hasn't changed anything... maybe it's not the function keys.

Comment: Your edit should be an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This appears to have been caused by a faulty or damaged headphone jack.

When I move/wiggle my headphone cable it triggers everything I described above. Connecting via bluetooth fixes this. (Maybe it's time for a new laptop...)